# Loop cut tool only select vertices (Blender)

Tags: vertices, geometry

I have the problem, that i can't create loop cuts on this specific face of the shape.
I need a vertical loop cut there. In loop cut blender just selects one of the vertices. On every edge i try it it don't appear. Does anyone have an idea what this could be due to.
Thanks for answers.[image]

Comment: you can't loopcut through a face that is not a quad, so use a knife instead, or subdivide the edge and join the opposite vertices with J

Answer (score 0):

Hey nnym  right click and subdivide it's works fine.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.